# Intersection of nested, non-empty compact subsets of a hausdorff topological space

Tags: general-topology

So I feel like I'm on the verge of solving this problem, but honestly don't know the crux. The question is:

Let $(X,T)$ be a topological space and let this space be hausdorff. Consider the infinite sequence $K_1⊇K_2⊇,...,⊇K_n⊇..$ of non-empty, compact subsets of $X$. Prove that their infinite intersection is non-empty.

So far I have written:

Assume that this intersection is empty. Consider $U_n = X$ $\backslash K_n$. (**Some of the following statements I will write without proofs)**.
Firstly, it is known that if X is hausdorff, then any compact subset of $X$ is closed. Additionally, for some $Z⊆K⊆X$, $Z$ too is compact.

This implies that for all $n$, $K_n$ is closed. It is also known that the intersection of an arbitrary family of closed subsets of $X$ is also closed. Therefore the intersection of all $K_n$ is closed too in $X$. **(Now I have just noticed when writing this, by assumption the intersection was the empty set which is an open set, so can the proof end here or did I do something wrong?**).

By definition, the compliment of a closed set is open. Then, $U_n$ is open in $X$. Define $Ω_n = K_1 $ \ $K_n$, and $Ω_n$ is an open set. $Ω_n$ then defines an open cover for $K_1$. As K is compact, there exists a finite sub-cover $(Ω_{n_1}, Ω_{n_2},..., Ω_{n_m})$.

I honestly don't know where to go from here at all, and in fact I'm not sure what I have written is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Note that $U_2 \subseteq U_3 \subseteq U_4 \subseteq \ldots$, and similar for the $\Omega_n$. What does that tell you about the union of a finite subfamily?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea. Also what is the point of me defining this subcover? I don't know what to do with it. Saying the union of the subcover equals the same set as the union of the open cover doesn't help me. I guess the union of $U_n$ would equal $X$, and the same for $Ω_n = K_n$? But how can I use this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close, you've got all the right pieces.

I think this might be a little easier if you phrase it as a proof by contradiction.
So, something like: `Assume to the contrary that $\bigcap K_n = \emptyset$, then the collection of $\Omega_n$ is an open cover of $K_1$'.

You've got the finite subcover $\{\Omega_{n_1}, \dots, \Omega_{n_m} \}$, and with Daniel's comment, you can make the following observation (hover over to get the hint, if you still need it):

> If w order things so that $n_1 < n_2 < \dots, n_m$, you have that $\Omega_{n_1} \subseteq \Omega_{n_1} \subseteq \dots \Omega_{n_m}$. Since $\{\Omega_{n_1}, \dots, \Omega_{n_m} \}$ is a cover of $K_1$, this means that the lone set $\Omega_{n_m}$ is a cover of $K_1$.

From that observation, you can complete the proof:

> But $\Omega_{n_m} = K_1 - K_{n_m}$. If $\Omega_{n_m}$ covers $K_1$, then $K_{n_m}$ must be empty! This contradicts the assumption that it is not empty, completing the proof.

Comment: Thank you for this! It really helped! One small issue I have is, why does $K_{n_m} = ∅$ imply that $K_n$ is empty too? (I didn't define $K_{n_m}$ earlier so it's a bit confusing)

Comment: $K_{n_m}$ is just one of the compact sets, except using new labels because you've found a few of those sets form a subcover and want to give them new names. The index $n_m$ should just be read as `some integer'. So you aren't saying $K_{n_m}$ empty implies $K_n$ empty at all.

Comment: Ahh I understand now! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The first part, with the complements relative to $X$ is not relevant, as we don't know anything about the compactness of $X$, so defining a cover of $X$ does not help us.

Just note that all sets $O_n = K_1\setminus K_n$ is closed in $K_1$, as it equals $K_1 \cap K_n^\complement$ and $K_n^\complement$ is open in $X$, as the complement of the compact (hence closed, by Hausdorffness of $X$!) set $K_n$.

We know that $n \le m$ implies $K_m \subseteq K_n$, so it follows that $n \le m$ also implies $O_n \le O_m$, so we have an increasing sequence of open subsets of $K_1$, starting at $C_1= \emptyset$.

Now the crucial observation is

$$(U_n)_n \text{ covers } K_1 \iff \cap_{n \ge 1} K_n = \emptyset$$

(Proof: suppose the left hand side holds, but $x$ is in the intersection of the $K_n$. In particular $x \in K_1$, so by the left hand side, $x \in U_m$ for some $m$, but then by definition $x \notin K_m$ for that $m$ too, while $x$ being in the intersection tells us $x \in K_m$ too! Contradiction and the intersection is empty. The proof from right to left is similar)

So the actual proof now can be finished: we assume (to get a contradiction) that $\bigcap_{n \ge 1} K_n = \emptyset$. By the previous equivalence $\{U_n\mid n \ge 1\}$ is a cover (!) of the compact $K_1$ so has a finite subcover, indexed $\{U_{n_1},\ldots, U_{n_k}\}$. Then setting $N=\max(n_1, \ldots, n_k)$ the increasingness of the $U_n$ implies that all $U_{n_i} \subseteq U_N$ and so the union, which is $K_1$ (as we have a subcover) equals $U_N= K_1 \setminus K_N$ and this happens only if $K_N = \emptyset$. We have our contradiction: it was **given** that all $K_n$ are non-empty! So $\bigcap_{n \ge 1} K_n \neq \emptyset$. QED.

Comment: Thanks, I like your approach too! Wish I could mark 2 answers as helpful